# Error integration SonarQube Msbuild runner with TeamCity

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, teamcity

I have a teamcity build, I've added to the build start and end actions to do a sonarqube analysis, and between those two task there is a build with msbuild. When SonarQube plugin executes the end phase it fails with this error.

```
[10:16:52][Step 5/9] Starting: C:\sonarqube\Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
[10:16:52][Step 5/9] in directory: C:\agents\build2\work\a6252c8eea7552b3\src
[10:16:52][Step 5/9] SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.0
[10:16:52][Step 5/9] Default properties file was found at C:\sonarqube\Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
[10:16:52][Step 5/9] Loading analysis properties from C:\sonarqube\Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Post-processing started.
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.1
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Possible causes:
[10:16:53][Step 5/9]   1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
[10:16:53][Step 5/9]   2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
[10:16:53][Step 5/9]   3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] 10:16:53.266  Creating a summary markdown file...
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Process exited with code 1
[10:16:53][Step 5/9] Step Finish SonarQube analysis (Command Line) failed
```

if I login to the server, open the very same directory of the agent and execute manually the three steps that the build executes.

```
C:\sonarqube\Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"Metrics.Net.Es" /n:"Metrics.Net.Es" /v:"1.0"
msbuild mysolution.sln
C:\sonarqube\Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

everything run just fine.

What could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I needed to specify the Working Directory to the MSBUILD run action in TeamCity. After I've set this value the analysis went ok. If I left this value blank, I got the previous error.

[image]

Gian Maria.

Comment: Actually I've given up configuring sonarqube with teamcity, and created a build with Visual Studio Team services, it is able to build github projects and have dedicated task for sonar qube analysis